# Unwanted space when using align and cases

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, cases

What I want, with manual alignment:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
    \ang{\varphi} \rightarrow \Omega_n\\
    \varphi^k \hspace{4.4pt}\mapsto \xi_n^k
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

With `align` I get unwanted space:

```
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
    \ang{\varphi} &\rightarrow \Omega_n\\
    \varphi^k &\mapsto \xi_n^k
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: You're misusing `cases` which is not for aligning at relation signs, but for aligning *conditions*

Comment: @egreg I just want the big curly bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using `aligned`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Original:
\[
  \begin{cases}
    \langle\varphi\rangle \rightarrow \Omega_n\\
    \varphi^k \hspace{4.4pt}\mapsto \xi_n^k
  \end{cases}
\]

Updated:
\[
  \left\{\begin{aligned}
    \langle\varphi\rangle &\rightarrow \Omega_n\\
    \varphi^k             &\mapsto \xi_n^k
  \end{aligned}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\]

\end{document}
```

You can also use `array`, but would have to [adjust for the vertical spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764) via `\arraystretch`.